# ReturnType<typeof F> where F is a function that returns type Promise<T>

Tags: typescript, promise, type-inference

I want to set the type of a variable to `T`.

If `F` was a function that did NOT return a promise and just returned an object of type `T`, I would just do something like this:
`let x: ReturnType<typeof F>`

But `F` is a function that returns a `Promise<T>`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the example given in the section [Type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) of Advanced Types chapter of the Typescript manual

```
type Unpacked<T> =
  T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U :
  T extends Promise<infer U> ? U :
  T;
```

For example for `fetch` you would get

```
type T = Unpacked<Unpacked<typeof fetch>>
// Response
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could do something like this:

```
async function sumAsync(a: number, b: number): Promise<number> {
  return a + b;
}

type SumUnwrappedType = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof sumAsync>>
```